# Upgrade cherrytree using snap?

Tags: ubuntu, snap

I have installed CherryTree 0.39.4 on ubuntu 20.04 using snap:

https://snapcraft.io/install/cherrytree/ubuntu

But based on (0.99.19 (November 7th, 2020)):
https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree/blob/master/changelog.txt

its seems the version from snap is very old.

Is its possible to get latest version 0.99.19 through snap or do I need to build it myself:

https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree#building-cherrytree-on-ubuntu-2004

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of installing with that Snap that someone created, you would be better off handling it with your package manager via their official PPA, as it suggests in their project's documentation: http://giuspen.com/cherrytreemanual/#_ubuntu

In your terminal, simply do: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:giuspen/ppa`

When I look to install applications, I always seek out the project's site, so in this case: https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/